# Securing specific nginx-ingress location with client cert verification

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, kubernetes-helm

I'm setting up an instance of ghost and I'm trying to secure the /ghost path with client cert verification.

I've got an initial ingress up and running that serves the site quite happily with the path specified as /.

I'm trying to add a second ingress (that's mostly the same) for the /ghost path. If I do this and add the annotations for basic auth, everything seems to work. i.e. If I browse to /ghost I am prompted for credentials in the basic-auth secret, if I browse to any other URL it is served without auth.

I then switched to client cert verification based on this example: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/master/docs/examples/auth/client-certs

When I try this either the whole site or none of the site is secured, rather than the path-based separation, I got with basic-auth. Looking at the nginx.conf from the running pod the  `proxy_set_header ssl-client-verify`, `proxy_set_header ssl-client-subject-dn` & `proxy_set_header ssl-client-issuer-dn` elements are added under the root / path and the /ghost path. I've tried removing those (from the root only) and copying the config directly back to the pod but not luck there either.

I'm pulling nginx-ingress (Chart version 0.23.0) in as a dependency via Helm

Ingress definition for `/` location - this one works

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-staging
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  labels:
    app: my-app
    chart: my-app-0.1.1
    heritage: Tiller
    release: my-app
  name: my-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-app
          servicePort: http
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: mysite-tls
```

Ingress definition for `/ghost` location - this one doesn't work

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "default/auth-tls-chain"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-error-page: "http://www.example.com/error-cert.html"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  labels:
    app: my-app
    chart: my-app-0.1.1
    heritage: Tiller
    release: my-app
  name: my-app-secure
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-app
          servicePort: http
        path: /ghost
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: mysite-tls
```

Comment: Can you post your Ingress definitions?

Comment: Now added the ingress definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `'*'` on your path on your second ingress if you want to serve all the pages securely under `/ghost` and if you want just `/ghost` you need another rule. Something like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "default/auth-tls-chain"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-error-page: "http://www.example.com/error-cert.html"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  labels:
    app: my-app
    chart: my-app-0.1.1
    heritage: Tiller
    release: my-app
  name: my-app-secure
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-app
          servicePort: http
        path: /ghost
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-app
          servicePort: http
        path: /ghost/*
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    secretName: mysite-tls
```

However, if you want something like `/` unsecured and `/ghost` secured, I believe you won't be able to do it. For example, if you are using nginx, this is a limitation from nginx itself, when you configure a [`server {}`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server) block with TLS in nginx it looks something like this:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         example.com;
    ssl_certificate     example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ...
}
```

The ingress controller creates paths like this:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         example.com;
    ssl_certificate     example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key example.com.key;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ...

    location / {
       ...
    }

    location /ghost {
       ...
    }

}
```

So when you configure another `server {}` block with the same hostname and with no SSL it will override the first one.

You could do it with different `- host:` rules in your ingress for example `ghost.example.com` with TLS and `main.example.com` without TLS. So in your nginx.conf you would have different `server {}` blocks.

You can always shell into the ingress controller pod to check the configs, for example:

```
$ kubectl exec -it nginx-ingress-controller-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxx bash
www-data@nginx-ingress-controller-6bd7c597cb-8kzjh:/etc/nginx$ cat nginx.conf
```

Comment: The problem isn't the multiple pages under ghost (although this will come in handy further down the line). The problem I've got is that all parts of the site are public other than the pages under ghost. I need the mutual auth to secure `/ghost/*` but not any other pages. At the minute the authentication is being applied to all pages

Comment: so you want `/` unsecured and `/ghost` secured?

Comment: Yeah, exactly that.

Comment: Added more details... hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Rico, that's been a great help. What I think I'll do it setup a second ingress and domain for the `/ghost` path and block it on the original one with a server snippet

Answer (score 0):

You could add a location-snippet

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/location-snippet: |
       if ($location ^~ ghost) {
          set $ban_info = "location";
       }

       if ($ssl_client_s_dn !~ "CN=ok_client") {
          set $ban_info = "${ban_info}+no_client";
       }

       if ($ban_info = "location+no_client") {
         return 403;
       }
```